# MVC 3 WebGrid Column Sort alphabatically, not according to table structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I have assigned data to the webgrid but it sorting the columns alphabetically. it is not showing columns as like in asp datagrid according to table structure.

for example if table have columns as"

```
id  title  artid
```

then grid showing them after sorting the columns as:

```
artid  id title
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are still looking for this answer I have found it here:

```
 <h2>Index</h2>
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model,
        defaultSort: "id",
        rowsPerPage:10);    
}
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<div id="grid">
    @grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
                    grid.Column("id", "ID"),
                    grid.Column("title", "Title"),
                    grid.Column("artist", "Artist")));
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: In addition to stuartmclark's post above, if you want to sort by descending, you can set the sort direction after your grid initialization.

grid.SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;

Answer (score 0):

In addition to stuartmclark's post above, if you want to sort by descending, you can set the sort direction after your grid initialization.

```
grid.SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
```