# columns doesn't appear in order in webgrid

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, webgrid

i am picking names from sql store procedure to display it in WEBGRID. I am usign MVC 3 and linq to sql.

but issue is that when i pick column names from database then it is not ordered as it is in Database.

e.g. in database it displays as

```
EmpName     EmpID     EmpShift
```

but in webgrid it appears

```
Empid     EmpShift    EmpID
```

Query:

```
with times as (
SELECT    t1.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , min(t1.RecTime) AS InTime
        , max(t2.RecTime) AS [TimeOut]
        , t4.ShiftId as ShiftID
        , t4.StAtdTime as ShStartTime
        , t4.EndAtdTime as ShEndTime
        , cast(min(t1.RecTime) as datetime) AS InTimeSub
        , cast(max(t2.RecTime) as datetime) AS TimeOutSub
        , t1.RecDate AS [DateVisited]
FROM  AtdRecord t1 
INNER JOIN 
      AtdRecord t2 
ON    t1.EmplID = t2.EmplID 
AND   t1.RecDate = t2.RecDate
AND   t1.RecTime < t2.RecTime
inner join 
      HrEmployee t3 
ON    t3.EmplID = t1.EmplID 
inner join AtdShiftSect t4
ON t3.ShiftId = t4.ShiftId
group by 
          t1.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , t1.RecDate
        , t4.ShiftId 
        , t4.StAtdTime 
        , t4.EndAtdTime
)
SELECT 
 EmplID
,EmplName
,ShiftId As ShiftID
,InTime
,[TimeOut]
,convert(char(5),cast([TimeOutSub] - InTimeSub as time), 108) TotalWorkingTime
,[DateVisited]
,CONVERT(char(5),CASE WHEN  CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME) >= ShEndTime And ShiftID = 'S002'
     Then  LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(12), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, CAST(ShEndTime AS DATETIME),  CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME)),0), 108),5) 
     WHEN  CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME) >= ShEndTime And ShiftID = 'S001'
     Then  LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(12), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, CAST(ShEndTime AS DATETIME),  CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME)),0), 108),5) 
     ELSE '00:00' END, 108) AS OverTime
FROM times order by EmplID, ShiftID, DateVisited
```

Webgrid output:

[image]

webgrid code:

```
public ActionResult showAllEmployees() 
        {
            IEnumerable<GetAtdRecord_SpResult> EmployeeAtd = DataContext.GetAtdRecord_Sp(null).ToList();
            var names = (from n in DataContext.HrEmployees select n).Distinct();
            return View(EmployeeAtd);
        }
```

view:

```
@{

    var grid = new WebGrid(ViewData.Model);

}

@grid.GetHtml()
```

Comment: Does my answer helped you? Or else please give me more information so that I can get you better answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default WebGrid Sorting Columns order is based on Alphabetical order. [To make it your own order, you have to specify columns in the WebGrid.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149964/mvc-3-webgrid-column-sort-alphabatically-not-according-to-table-structure)